# bash function no longer found

Tags: bash, shell

Do **bash** functions get "pushed out of the system" if they haven't been used in a while and the system needs memory (or whatever)?

Allow me to explain. For what it's worth, I've inherited a scripting project (it should have been moved a long time ago to compiled code) that's used to do a large series of calculations, running over and over, retrying values, attempting to calibrate a machine. The main script sources another script file to pull in helper functions `source ${binpath}/helper.sh` at the very start, and then runs for 3-4 hours doing it's thing.

It's at *the very end*, naturally, when it goes to call two functions in **helper.sh** that it's not finding them. I have verified things by hand - the function calls are labeled correctly, spelled correctly and (thanks to **set -x**) work when called outside the script.

The only thing I can think of is that, given the amount of time and the amount of calculcations, the system saw these two functions as being unused and trashed them.

So I'm wondering -- is that a thing?

Comment: Nope, it's not a thing. Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? One without the 3-4 hour delay, naturally.

Comment: About the only way I can think of for this to happen is to have the function not exported, then `exec` into a new environment and trying to call the (now no longer available) function, but yes, the example would be helpful.

Comment: Please do echo "source ${binpath}/helper.sh" > /tmp/log.txt and put an exit after, then see if the path has the correct script.

Comment: In general, computers don't forget things by themselves. You have to do something that causes the information to be discarded, overwritten, etc.

Comment: I suggest that at strategic points in your scripts you do a `declare -F` to list the functions you have, redirected to a log file.  Also `echo` to the same file something to identify where you are in the procedure.  You are loosing those functions somehow, it's a case of narrowing down where it is.

Comment: I've seen something like this with a script in a directory that gets removed and replaced when the script is logged to that dir, but not with a function... Could `$binpath` get changed? Not that it should matter as written...

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get when you try to call the function?

Comment: The exact error message is "command not found" with the script name, line number and the command that it couldn't find.

Comment: I like the suggestion of adding the `declare -F` to the script, I will do that and see what it shows, thanks!